# Error in configuring openmpi 64 bit on a linux machine using intel compiler

Tags: linux, mpi, x86-64, openmpi, icc

While configuring openmpi with 64 bit using intel compiler, I got this error:

```
checking if sizeof(C int) == sizeof(Fortran INTEGER)... no

=========================================================================
                        ERROR   ERROR    ERROR

Configure has detected that the size of a C integer (4 bytes) is
different than the size of a Fortran INTEGER (8 bytes).  In the
entire v3.x and v4.x series of Open MPI, this configuration is known
to cause data corruption with the mpi_f08 module (it does *not* cause
problems with mpif.h or the mpi module bindings).

You may either choose to change the C and/or Fortran compiler flags
(in order to have the size of a C int be the same as the size of a
Fortran INTEGER) and re-run configure, or you may specify the
--enable-mpi-fortran=usempi flag to configure to explicitly
disable building the mpi_f08 module.

(NOTE: this error has been fixed in Open MPI releases beyond v4.x)
```

which compiler flags have to be included in order to change the C int size to 8 bytes?

This is what I used:
./configure CXX=icpc CC=icc F77=ifort FC=ifort FFLAGS=-i8  FCFLAGS=-i8

Comment: you cannot change the `C` `int` size. but you can copy/paste the full error message, read it, and choose the workaround you want to use.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thanks! I just updated with the full error message - what would be a workaround for this?

Comment: Do not build the Fortran 2008 bindings.

Comment: Why do you want Fortran's INTEGER to be 8 bytes? Linux is LP64, which means only long integer and pointers are 8 bytes long. Anything else is non-standard. You only need to build with `-i8` if you have to use MPI specifically with other Fortran code that was built with 8-byte long integers.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: @HristoIliev I need to use MPI with a Fortran code build with 8-byte long integers.

Answer (score 0):

For example, building OpenMPI-i8 with Intel compilers:

./configure --prefix=  FC=ifort FCFLAGS=-i8  CC=icc CFLAGS=-m64 CXX=icpc CXXFLAGS=-m64 --enable-mpi-fortran=usempi